Print DataFrame without index column
Is there a way to print a DataFrame to the console in JavaScript without including the ugly index column? Here is my current code. I am use dataframe-js but willing to try other JavaScript libraries.
export function printDataframe(data) {
    const df = new DataFrame(data); 

    console.table(df.toCollection());
}

